# javascript for showing divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

script code when user clicks button the 1st div (#1-div) shows and when they click again 2nd div (#2-div) shows...etc

Here is what I worked on so far:

'''

```
<head>
    <style>
        #div-1, #div-2, #div-3{
          display: none;
          width: 100%;
          padding: 50px 0;
          text-align: center;
          background-color: lightblue;
          margin-top: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="number" value="0"/>
</form>
<p>What is the color of the ocean?</p>
<div id="div-1">
    <p>What is the color of the sky?</p>
</div>
<div id="div-2">
    <p>What is the color of the sand?</p>
</div>
<div id="div-3">
    <p>What is the color of the bus?</p>
</div>


<button onclick="nextQuestion()">Next Question</button>

<script>
function nextQuestion()
{

}
</script>
```

'''

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp have a read

Comment: I have seen this one before. The only issue is I need to have some kind of counter variable and if conditional to show the div's in sequence i.e. 1...2...3.... Not good with creating j-script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember the index of current shown element, and increase it by +1 after each click:

```js
let question = document.querySelectorAll(".question");
let index = 0;

show(question[index]);

document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", function _tmp() {
  hide(question[index]);
  index++;
  
  if( !question[index] ) {
    this.removeEventListener("click", _tmp);
    this.textContent = "No more questions!";
    // this keyword refers to context of function call (here: The clicked button)
    return;
  }
  
  show(question[index]);
});

/***/
function show(el, value) {
  el.style.display = value || "block";
}
function hide(el) {
  el.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.question {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button id="next">Next Question</button>
<hr>

<div class="question">
  <p>What is the color of the ocean?</p>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <p>What is the color of the sky?</p>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <p>What is the color of the sand?</p>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <p>What is the color of the bus?</p>
</div>
```

P.s. If numbered ids, class names, variables, etc. appear in your code, that means, something went wrong) Try to solve the problem in more general way, with loops, arrays.